# Writing nested while commands properly without errors

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, newline

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // variables
    int door,base;
    char ch;
    int a,b,bin;
    int converter,converterC,controller = 0;
    printf("Welcome to Full Subtractor!\n");
    printf("\t(1)\tCompute and Display the outputs\n");
    printf("\t(2)\tQuit \n");
    printf("You choose:");
    scanf("%d",&door);

    while(door == 1)
    {
        printf("\nYou have chosen option %d\n",door);
        printf("Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)? ");
        scanf("%d",&base);

        while(base == 2)
        {
            printf("Please enter your input: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            while(ch!= '\n')
            {

                scanf("%c", &ch);

                converter = ch - '0'; // convert char to int
                converterC = converterC+1;
                controller = controller+1;

                if(converterC == 0)
                {
                    a = converter;
                }
                else if(converterC == 1)
                {
                    b = converter;
                }
                else if(converterC == 2)
                {
                    bin = converter;
                }


            }


            if(controller <=3)
            {
                printf("\nYou entered less than 3 bits! Please try again!\n");
                break;
            }
            else if(controller > 4)
            {
                printf("\nYou entered more than 3 bits! Please try again!\n");
                break;
            }

        }
        while(base == 16)
        {
            printf("xxxxx");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want the output to be like this but this is not working properly:

Welcome to Full Subtractor!

(1) Compute and Display the outputs
(2) Quit You choose: 1
You have chosen option 1

Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)? 2
Please enter your input: 111
D is 1 Bout is 1

Welcome to Full Subtractor!

(1) Compute and Display the outputs
(2) Quit You choose: 1
You have chosen option 1

Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)? 2
Please enter your input: 22
Invalid number in base 2! Please try again!
Please enter your input: 1110001
You entered more than 3 bits! Please try again!
Please enter your input: E
Invalid number in base 2! Please try again! Please enter your input:011
D is 0 Bout is 1

I want seperate every ch and to convert to int and I will use for calculating one by one but this while loop it isnt working properly
my output:
Welcome to Full Subtractor!
(1)     Compute and Display the outputs
(2)     Quit
You choose:1

You have chosen option 1
Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)?2
Please enter your input:1
Please enter your input:
You entered less than 3 bits! Please try again!

You have chosen option 1
Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)?2

You entered less than 3 bits! Please try again!

You have chosen option 1
Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)?

---OR
Welcome to Full Subtractor!
(1)     Compute and Display the outputs
(2)     Quit
You choose:1

You have chosen option 1
Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)?2
Please enter your input:0000
Please enter your input: Please ent
er your input: Please enter your input: Please enter your input:
You entered more than 3 bits! Please try again!

You have chosen option 1
Which base will you use to enter input (base 2 or base 16)?

I want it ask input again. btw array and operators are forbidden.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Without reading it all, you say `while door ==...) {}` but don't change door inside the loop

Comment: To answer the question, people must understand what you have and what you want. It looks like the information is there (great!), but because of bad formatting it's hard to see. Please [edit] your question and improve formatting (you can use `<pre>` and `</pre>` to mark the beginning and end of your input and output sections).

Comment: You *must* always check the value returned by scanf.  eg `if( 1 != scanf("%d", ...) ) { /* program did not assign any values; this issue condition must be handled */ ; }`  In particular, since `door` is not initialized, the code `scanf("%d", &door); while(door == 1)` is undefined behavior for a large class of inputs.

Comment: Also, since `ch` was not initialized, `while(ch!= '\n')` is always undefined behavior on the first iteration in your program.

Comment: What do you mean by `btw array and operators are forbidden.`  Your current program uses assignment operators often, so clearly not all operators are forbidden.  As to  `How can I fix that?`; you can allow yourself to use operators and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this call of `fflush`

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

The variable `ch` was not initialized

```
char ch;
```

So this while loop

```
while(ch!= '\n')
```

invokes undefined behavior.

The same problem exists with the variable `converterC` that also was not initialized and used in this statement

```
converterC = converterC+1;
```

Another problem with the code is that after this input

```
scanf("%d",&base);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

So this call of `scanf`

```
 scanf("%c", &ch);
```

at once reads the new line character.

Before the while loop you could insert one more loop to remove from the input buffer the new line character `'\n'` like

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
```

The original while loop is better to rewrite as an infinite while loop as for example

while ( getchar() != '\n' );

```
while( 1 )
{
    if ( scanf("%c", &ch) != 1 || ch == '\n' ) break;
    //...
}
```

And do not forget to initialize variables `converterC` and `controller` to zeroes each time before entering the while loop.